# Checkall checkbox for grouped data in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, group-by

I am getting grouped data in mvc grid(grouped on the basis of a column). I am trying to create a checkbox in the group header on clicking of which all the checkboxes within that group header gets selected.

```
@foreach(var group in Model.GroupBy(x=>x.Column)){
    {
        <tr class="group-header">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" 
                 onchange="toggleSelect(this.checked)">
            </td>
            <td colspan="6">
                <span class="h3">@group.Key</span>
            </td>
        </tr> 
        foreach(var item in group)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup">
                </td>
                <td>
                    ...
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

jQuery for toggleSelect()

```
function toggleSelect()status{
    $('.checkGroup').prop('checked',status);
}
```

When I use this all the checkboxes gets checked since all the checkboxes have same class(ckeckGroup). But I need only the checkboxes within a group to be checked. And the grouping to be used is dynamic so I cannot predefine any group. How can that be done?

Comment: Declare a 'counter' before your `outer @foreach` loop and increment it in the loop - `counter++;` and use its value to create a class name

Comment: Also remove your `id="checkAll"` - duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is adding the same css class to all the rows, hence your change is applied to all those rows. Ideally you need to to have some sort of connection between the group header row/checkbox with the grouped rows under that.

You are also setting the same `Id` to all group header chekboxes inside the loop, which will create more than one chekbox with the Id value `checkAll`, which is invalid HTML. Id's in a document should be unique.

Use a simple counter variable and use that to group rows. In the below sample, i am using html5 data attributes to group my rows.

```
@{
    var keyCounter = 1;
}
@foreach(var group in Model.GroupBy(x=>x.Column)){
{
    <tr class="group-header">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" data-group-id="@keyCounter">
        </td>
        <td colspan="6">
            <span class="h3">@group.Key</span>
        </td>
    </tr> 
    foreach(var item in group)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox"  data-group="@keyCounter">
            </td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
        </tr>
    }  
    keyCounter++;
}
```

This will basically generate markup  for the header checkbox like this

```
<input type="checkbox" data-group-id="1">
```

and the associated rows will have checkbox like this

```
<input type="checkbox" data-group="1">
```

where `1` will be replaced with the actual value of `keyCounter` as the loop progresses.

Now all you have to do is, wire up the `change` event on our header row checkboxes and toggle the checked property of the associated check boxes

```
$(function() {

    $("input[data-group-id]").change(function(e) {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
        var groupId = $(this).data("group-id");
        var groupedRows = $("input[data-group='" + groupId + "']");
        groupedRows.prop("checked", isChecked);
    });

})
```

If `group.Key` is a numeric value or a small string (without spaces), you can use that instead of the `keyCounter` variable.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/lefiyuw/edit?html,js,output) is a working jsbin for your reference.